# Did I brick my PNY GTX 1080ti oc 11g graphics card?

Tags: power-supply, gpu, pci, hardware-detection

I'm here to ask if I messed up and burned my new 1080Ti xlr8 oc graphics card.

I have a 500w PSU (ZALMAN500-HP). When I took out my old GTX 750Ti and plugged in my new GPU, my PC didn't work.

The monitors did not work at all (I have 3x Monitors 24" 52" and 19").
When I asked a friend he said I needed to connect PCI cables from the PSU to the GPU! I searched for the PCI cables, but I found only 1x PCI 6-pin available! but my GPU needs 1x 6-pin and 1x 8-pin!

My country is under full lockdown because of COVID-19 and I couldn't buy a new PSU or adapter cable, so I did the following:

1. I had a broken PSU in my home I cut off a PCI cable 6-pin+2 from it.
2. I made a little openings on the PCI 6-pin cable (the one from my working PSU).
3. I connected the top 3x yellow cables of the 6pin+2 with the top 3x yellow cables of the 6-pin (the one I cut from my old PSU).
4. I connected the bottom 3x black cables of the 6-pin+2 with the bottom 3x black cables of the 6-pin (the one I cut from my old PSU).

Diagram:

[image]

Now I had 6-pin and 6-pin+2 PCI cables (at least that's what I thought I had)...

[image: Final result]

but when I connected them to the GPU and clicked on the power button my monitor flashed for a second with a red screen (It was a super fast red flash) then the screen went dark. After about  4 seconds the screen turned on with a glitchy red screen (no image on it, no writing, just a glitchy red screen) for ~2 seconds then it went black! I got scared and I unplugged the power for the whole system.

Did I mess up with modifying my 6-pin and brick my new GPU? If not why the red screen and why didn't it work when I booted my PC?

Comment: “my question is: did i messed up with modifying my 6pin and burned my new GPU?” - Yes; This is very likely;

Comment: You may get an answer here, but you might have better luck posting this on [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: EE is really hostile to questions that appear to have anything to do with computers even if the question is purely electronics/wiring in nature. Be warned that you may have to fight off overzealous close votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm here to To answer my own Question, 
it Truned that the mod that i did to the 6pin with a 6pin+2 was Clean and correct! 
and the GPU Didnt burn out it still fine!. 
The red Screen turned to be a HDMI Cable Problem! 
so when i changed my HDMI Cable the GPU worked just fine still it wont do any heavy work since my PSU is very low
so i bought a new PSU 750W with 2x PCI 6pin+2 and everything is fine and nothing got dmged from the 1st test!
in the end i would like to Thank you for your replays.

Answer (score 1):

You may have fried the GPU, the motherboard or the power-supply. Or any combination of those. (Motherboard is very unlikely though.)

First undo your wiring mess and put the old Gfx card back in. See it that still works. If so your motherboard and PSU are fine.
(If you don't have the old card anymore, borrow a known good card. You should NOT be able to break it just be testing this. Just be sure you cut the power immediately if it doesn't work right away. )

Second step: Normally a GPU having 2 power-connectors will fire up with 1 monitor if only the 6-pin is attached.
It will not get full power, but should get enough to get you into Windows with 1 monitor working. It won't do anything graphics intensive, like gaming, in that case.
So try that. If it works, you are very lucky and didn't fry anything.

Than there are 3 things to consider:

1. Did you wire the plugs correctly? It ought to work, but be VERY careful you have the connectors in the right orientation. You could have wired the 8-pin "upside-down" which effectively short-circuits the PSU. It depends on the quality of the PSU if it can survive that for a brief period. Most don't.
2. Can the PSU deliver enough power for your setup? Depending on the motherboard, the GFX card and other stuff (like harddisks) your 500W may not be powerful enough.
3. Can the PSU deliver enough power on the wires to the 6-pin connector to also power the 8-pin? This is often NOT the case. So, even if your wiring was OK, you may have overloaded the PSU. In that case the PSU is probably fine, it just tripped an internal safety.

Your best bet is to order a molex to PCIe 8-pin converter cable online and use that to power the 8-pin on the PSU from the power-rail that normally supplies power to the harddisk(s). That is what most of us do when fazed with a lack of appropriate power-connectors.

As for COVID shutdown: Even with lock-down post-order still works in most countries. How did you get that new GFX card in the first place? I'm guessing you just didn't have the patience to wait 3-4 days for delivery of a proper power-cable, so you tried to hot-wire it.

If you're lucky everything survived. If you're not... It is going to be expensive...

Comment: Hello Tonny, Thank you for the detailed comment, i got the GTX* 1080Ti xlr8 oc through one of my contacts that works as a Ploice Officer (since they can travel between cities.) anyway thats not the problem.
1/ about wiring the plugs i already uploaded a picture about the wiring.
2/my PSU and Motherboard are safe im already using them now with my old GPU. 
3/ the 6pin cable was not linked anywhere since the start and still i didnt take off the 6pin+2 that i added to it untill now, even when im using it, that tells me the wiring was correct (i guess)

Comment: 4/ when i connect the GTX 1080ti 11g to the motherboard now without plugging the PCI cables the fans of the GPU works fine and there was no burn smell no noise when i first tested the moded 6pin does that mean that the GPU still fine! ?

Comment: @xRaijin Anything is possible. Just triple check you have both plugs (6 and 8 pin) wired correctly. These plugs are keyed. They only go in the connector one-way. (Although you CAN insert them upside down if you force it and sometimes connectors are loose enough you can insert them wrong by accident without forcing it.) So make absolutely sure the yellow and black match with the orientation of the keys.

Comment: Yes Sir! i am 10000% sure that i did not force the 6pin and 6pin+2 when pluging them to the GPU and im sure that the plugs shapes was matching the GPU connectors shap i even still remember the sound of the safty Clips when they got attached and over all of that i just did try to plug the 6pin & the 6pin+2 again to the GPU (ofc the PSU is off hh) and they didnt went in when i want to plug them the wrong way even with a strong force and i dont remember forcing them when i plugged them the 1st time. so yes im 100% sure the yellow and black match the orientation of the keys.